# Swagger2 UI Resource mapping and API Documentation is missing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

This is a Spring Boot project.
I have added Spring Fox a Swagger 2 based API documentation tool to my .pom file and I have
configured it but for some reason (my guess is the resource mapping is not working properly)
The basic part of the confguration is there but when I have added more specific configuration,
like my contact or description of the API -> this part is not showing.

This is my Swagger configuration class:

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:springFoxdocumentation.yml")
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringFoxConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer  {

    @Value("${api.common.version}")
    private static String apiVersion;
    @Value("${api.common.title}")
    private static String apiTitle;
    @Value("${api.common.description}")
    private static String apiDescription;
    @Value("${api.common.termsOfServiceUrl}")
    private static String apiTermsOfServiceUrl;
    @Value("${api.common.license}")
    private static String apiLicense;
    @Value("${api.common.licenseUrl}")
    private static String apiLicenseUrl;
    @Value("${api.common.contact.name}")
    private static String apiContactName;
    @Value("${api.common.contact.url}")
    private static String apiContactUrl;
    @Value("${api.common.contact.email}")
    private static String apiContactEmail;



    @Bean
    public Docket apiDocumentation(){
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                    .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.GET, Collections.emptyList())
                    .apiInfo(new ApiInfo(
                        apiVersion,
                        apiTitle,
                        apiDescription,
                        apiTermsOfServiceUrl,
                        new Contact( apiContactName, apiContactUrl,apiContactEmail),
                        apiLicense,
                        apiLicenseUrl,
                        Collections.emptyList()
                    ));
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

}
```

I know that I shouldn't have there the resource handler method, but since I have assumed that this problem is caused by resource mapper I have added it int the code (but it didn't help)

And this is my .yml file under **resources** folder

```
api:
  common:
    version: 1.0.0
    title: Ticket Manager
    description: Ticket Manager server as a simple REST API for managing ticket and Incidents
    termsOfServiceUrl: LINK FOR TERMS OF SERVICE
    license: This is a Open Source Licensed product
    licenseUrl: LINK FOR LICENSE URL
    contact:
      name: opensourcedev
      url: URL FOR OPENSOURCEDEV
      email: sample@gmail.com
```

And finally this is a log from my application when I launch swagger2 html page **http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html#/**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.3.RELEASE)

2020-10-18 18:26:36.651  INFO 14928 --- [           main] c.o.t.TicketManagerApplication           : Starting TicketManagerApplication on DESKTOP-FJ83RN4 with PID 14928 (D:\Git Projects\ticket-manager\target\classes started by sajmo in D:\Git Projects\ticket-manager)
2020-10-18 18:26:36.653  INFO 14928 --- [           main] c.o.t.TicketManagerApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-10-18 18:26:37.378  INFO 14928 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-10-18 18:26:37.436  INFO 14928 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 51ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-10-18 18:26:37.832  INFO 14928 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-10-18 18:26:37.840  INFO 14928 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-10-18 18:26:37.840  INFO 14928 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.37]
2020-10-18 18:26:37.962  INFO 14928 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-10-18 18:26:37.962  INFO 14928 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1258 ms
2020-10-18 18:26:38.063  INFO 14928 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-10-18 18:26:38.087  INFO 14928 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Autowired annotation is not supported on static fields: private static java.lang.String com.opensourcedev.ticketmanager.apidocs.SpringFoxConfig.apiVersion
2020-10-18 18:26:38.088  INFO 14928 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Autowired annotation is not supported on static fields: private static java.lang.String com.opensourcedev.ticketmanager.apidocs.SpringFoxConfig.apiTitle
2020-10-18 18:26:38.088  INFO 14928 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Autowired annotation is not supported on static fields: private static java.lang.String com.opensourcedev.ticketmanager.apidocs.SpringFoxConfig.apiDescription
2020-10-18 18:26:38.088  INFO 14928 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Autowired annotation is not supported on static fields: private static java.lang.String com.opensourcedev.ticketmanager.apidocs.SpringFoxConfig.apiTermsOfServiceUrl
2020-10-18 18:26:38.088  INFO 14928 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Autowired annotation is not supported on static fields: private static java.lang.String com.opensourcedev.ticketmanager.apidocs.SpringFoxConfig.apiLicense
2020-10-18 18:26:38.088  INFO 14928 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Autowired annotation is not supported on static fields: private static java.lang.String com.opensourcedev.ticketmanager.apidocs.SpringFoxConfig.apiLicenseUrl
2020-10-18 18:26:38.088  INFO 14928 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Autowired annotation is not supported on static fields: private static java.lang.String com.opensourcedev.ticketmanager.apidocs.SpringFoxConfig.apiContactName
2020-10-18 18:26:38.088  INFO 14928 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Autowired annotation is not supported on static fields: private static java.lang.String com.opensourcedev.ticketmanager.apidocs.SpringFoxConfig.apiContactUrl
2020-10-18 18:26:38.088  INFO 14928 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Autowired annotation is not supported on static fields: private static java.lang.String com.opensourcedev.ticketmanager.apidocs.SpringFoxConfig.apiContactEmail
2020-10-18 18:26:38.246  WARN 14928 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-10-18 18:26:38.273  INFO 14928 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-10-18 18:26:38.303 DEBUG 14928 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 17 mappings in 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'
2020-10-18 18:26:38.353  INFO 14928 --- [           main] pertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/v2/api-docs] onto method [springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller#getDocumentation(String, HttpServletRequest)]
2020-10-18 18:26:38.373 DEBUG 14928 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Patterns [/swagger-ui.html, /webjars/**] in 'resourceHandlerMapping'
2020-10-18 18:26:38.427 DEBUG 14928 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ModelAttribute, 0 @InitBinder, 1 RequestBodyAdvice, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2020-10-18 18:26:38.448 DEBUG 14928 --- [           main] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ExceptionHandler, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2020-10-18 18:26:38.567  INFO 14928 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-10-18 18:26:38.587  INFO 14928 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-10-18 18:26:38.588  INFO 14928 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Context refreshed
2020-10-18 18:26:38.602  INFO 14928 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
2020-10-18 18:26:38.627  INFO 14928 --- [           main] s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner     : Scanning for api listing references
2020-10-18 18:26:38.753  INFO 14928 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: deleteUsingDELETE_1
2020-10-18 18:26:38.770  INFO 14928 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: findAllTicketsUsingGET_1
2020-10-18 18:26:38.773  INFO 14928 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: findByIdUsingGET_1
2020-10-18 18:26:38.783  INFO 14928 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: saveUsingPOST_1
2020-10-18 18:26:38.786  INFO 14928 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: deleteUsingDELETE_2
2020-10-18 18:26:38.787  INFO 14928 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: deleteUsingDELETE_3
2020-10-18 18:26:38.791  INFO 14928 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: findAllTicketsUsingGET_2
2020-10-18 18:26:38.792  INFO 14928 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: findAllTicketsUsingGET_3
2020-10-18 18:26:38.795  INFO 14928 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: findbyIdUsingGET_1
2020-10-18 18:26:38.800  INFO 14928 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: saveUsingPOST_2
2020-10-18 18:26:38.801  INFO 14928 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: saveUsingPOST_3
2020-10-18 18:26:38.803  INFO 14928 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: deleteUsingDELETE_4
2020-10-18 18:26:38.804  INFO 14928 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: deleteUsingDELETE_5
2020-10-18 18:26:38.809  INFO 14928 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: findAllTicketsUsingGET_4
2020-10-18 18:26:38.809  INFO 14928 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: findAllTicketsUsingGET_5
2020-10-18 18:26:38.812  INFO 14928 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: findbyIdUsingGET_2
2020-10-18 18:26:38.813  INFO 14928 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: findbyIdUsingGET_3
2020-10-18 18:26:38.817  INFO 14928 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: saveUsingPOST_4
2020-10-18 18:26:38.818  INFO 14928 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: saveUsingPOST_5
2020-10-18 18:26:38.826  INFO 14928 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2020-10-18 18:26:39.291  INFO 14928 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-10-18 18:26:39.428  INFO 14928 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-10-18 18:26:39.436  INFO 14928 --- [           main] c.o.t.TicketManagerApplication           : Started TicketManagerApplication in 3.057 seconds (JVM running for 3.892)
2020-10-18 18:26:50.042  INFO 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-10-18 18:26:50.042  INFO 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-10-18 18:26:50.042 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2020-10-18 18:26:50.047 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2020-10-18 18:26:50.047  INFO 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 5 ms
2020-10-18 18:26:50.053 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/v2/api-docs", parameters={}
2020-10-18 18:26:50.168 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json;q=0.8', given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2020-10-18 18:26:50.169 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json@51a025e9]
2020-10-18 18:26:50.178 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2020-10-18 18:27:24.254 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/swagger-ui.html", parameters={}
2020-10-18 18:27:24.257 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/"]
2020-10-18 18:27:24.262 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 304 NOT_MODIFIED
2020-10-18 18:27:24.391 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", parameters={}
2020-10-18 18:27:24.392 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController#uiConfiguration()
2020-10-18 18:27:24.393 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/favicon-32x32.png?v=2.9.2", parameters={masked}
2020-10-18 18:27:24.394 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"]
2020-10-18 18:27:24.397 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2020-10-18 18:27:24.398 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [application/json] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2020-10-18 18:27:24.398 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [springfox.documentation.swagger.web.UiConfiguration@674d67e1]
2020-10-18 18:27:24.400 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2020-10-18 18:27:24.404 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/swagger-resources/configuration/security", parameters={}
2020-10-18 18:27:24.404 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController#securityConfiguration()
2020-10-18 18:27:24.406 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [application/json] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2020-10-18 18:27:24.406 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SecurityConfiguration@466a47c4]
2020-10-18 18:27:24.407 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2020-10-18 18:27:24.410 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/swagger-resources", parameters={}
2020-10-18 18:27:24.410 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController#swaggerResources()
2020-10-18 18:27:24.411 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [application/json] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2020-10-18 18:27:24.411 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [[springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SwaggerResource@592c2c2f]]
2020-10-18 18:27:24.413 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2020-10-18 18:27:24.445 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/", parameters={}
2020-10-18 18:27:24.445 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/v2/api-docs", parameters={}
2020-10-18 18:27:24.446  WARN 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /
2020-10-18 18:27:24.446 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2020-10-18 18:27:24.449 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2020-10-18 18:27:24.450 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2020-10-18 18:27:24.452 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2020-10-18 18:27:24.453 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Sun Oct 18 18:27:24 CEST 2020, status=404, error=Not Found, message=, path=/}]
2020-10-18 18:27:24.454 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
2020-10-18 18:27:24.458 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/csrf", parameters={}
2020-10-18 18:27:24.458 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [application/json, */*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2020-10-18 18:27:24.458 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json@784dbf0b]
2020-10-18 18:27:24.458  WARN 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /csrf
2020-10-18 18:27:24.458 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2020-10-18 18:27:24.458 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2020-10-18 18:27:24.459 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2020-10-18 18:27:24.459 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2020-10-18 18:27:24.459 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2020-10-18 18:27:24.459 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Sun Oct 18 18:27:24 CEST 2020, status=404, error=Not Found, message=, path=/csrf}]
2020-10-18 18:27:24.460 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
2020-10-18 18:29:06.678 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", parameters={}
2020-10-18 18:29:06.678 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController#uiConfiguration()
2020-10-18 18:29:06.679 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [application/json] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2020-10-18 18:29:06.679 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [springfox.documentation.swagger.web.UiConfiguration@7fcb7c22]
2020-10-18 18:29:06.680 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2020-10-18 18:29:06.684 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/swagger-resources/configuration/security", parameters={}
2020-10-18 18:29:06.684 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController#securityConfiguration()
2020-10-18 18:29:06.685 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [application/json] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2020-10-18 18:29:06.685 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SecurityConfiguration@5c5535f8]
2020-10-18 18:29:06.686 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2020-10-18 18:29:06.689 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/swagger-resources", parameters={}
2020-10-18 18:29:06.689 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController#swaggerResources()
2020-10-18 18:29:06.689 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [application/json] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2020-10-18 18:29:06.690 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [[springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SwaggerResource@59507de0]]
2020-10-18 18:29:06.690 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2020-10-18 18:29:06.719 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/v2/api-docs", parameters={}
2020-10-18 18:29:06.720 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/", parameters={}
2020-10-18 18:29:06.721  WARN 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /
2020-10-18 18:29:06.721 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2020-10-18 18:29:06.721 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2020-10-18 18:29:06.721 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2020-10-18 18:29:06.722 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2020-10-18 18:29:06.722 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Sun Oct 18 18:29:06 CEST 2020, status=404, error=Not Found, message=, path=/}]
2020-10-18 18:29:06.723 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
2020-10-18 18:29:06.726 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [application/json, */*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2020-10-18 18:29:06.726 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json@786c5618]
2020-10-18 18:29:06.727 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2020-10-18 18:29:06.744 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/csrf", parameters={}
2020-10-18 18:29:06.745  WARN 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /csrf
2020-10-18 18:29:06.745 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2020-10-18 18:29:06.745 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2020-10-18 18:29:06.746 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2020-10-18 18:29:06.746 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2020-10-18 18:29:06.746 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Sun Oct 18 18:29:06 CEST 2020, status=404, error=Not Found, message=, path=/csrf}]
2020-10-18 18:29:06.747 DEBUG 14928 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

Comment: have you added swagger-ui in your pom.xml ? which version of springfox you are using?

Comment: Sorry for not adding this information into original question but I was limited to 3 000 chars 
`<dependency>
   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
   <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
   <version>2.9.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
   <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
   <version>2.9.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>`

Comment: Ok, so from what I can see, the Swagger is in the end working fine but it is not displaying the content from method apiDocumentation(), to be specific from the ApiInfo object.
Idk if the problem is that Spring Boot is not reading the properties or what

Comment: Have you tried using string values instead of values from properties? If swagger can show string values, then you can be sure that the problem lies with reading property files.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but instead of '@Value' properties I have added there String properties directly and it is workling. But now the question is, why is the '@Value' not working. I have added there even a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer and it doesn't seems to fix the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your code. First of all, `@Value` does not work on static fields. So all your springfox declared fields are null. Spring never set values in them.
If you remove the static from your fields , Spring will tell you that it doesn't find the properties like `api.common.version` or `api.common.title`. Because `@PropertySource` does not load yml files. It is declared in official [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml-shortcomings).

But there are workaround, you can follow this source [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml-propertysource) to use yml files with `@PropertySource`.